# Limit of two variables (apparently $+\infty$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am practising limits of two variables and all its methods (with polar coordinates, along different curves...) but I have found this one:
$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy+1}{x^2-y}$.
When simply substituting $x=y=0$,it follows that the value of the limit would be $+\infty$ (with no need of recurring to additional methods) but I am a bit confused because I have never obtained a limit of two variables  which is not finite. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: prove on certain paths of the form $y=kx^2$ the divergence is to $\infty$ while on others it's to $-\infty$.

Comment: Alright @J.G. For example, with $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2$ is $\infty$ and with $y=2x^2$ is $-\infty$; so the limit does not exist. Anyway, there exist functions of two variables with a limit which is not finite? Because doing exercises I have found any. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you asking for an example where $\lim_{(x,\,y)\to(0,\,0)}f(x,\,y)$ is $+\infty$ rather than not existing or being $-\infty$ or something finite? If so, take $f=1/(xy)^2$.

Comment: Ok, understood!

Comment: Compare the limit along the line $y=0$ to the limit along $x=0$.